# Why my code textContent.indexOf can't compare input value

Tags: javascript, html

The code worked a few months ago and recently stopped working

It's for when I text some word and it can auto search the item of list

I have been trying code from a lesson but it still doesn't work

This is my code

```js
function search() {
  let search = document.querySelector('#search');
  let li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  for (let data of li) {
    console.log(data.textContent.indexOf(search))
    if (data.textContent.indexOf(search) > -1) {
      data.style.display = '';
    } else {
      data.style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="search()">
<ul id="phone">
  <li>iPhone 12</li>
  <li>iPhone 12 Pro</li>
  <li>iPhone 12 Pro Max</li>
  <li>iPhone 12 Mini</li>
  <li>iPad Air</li>
  <li>iPad Pro</li>
  <li>iMac</li>
  <li>Mac book Air</li>
  <li>Mac book Pro</li>
  <li>Mac Pro</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please define what "doesn't work" means. Do you get an error? Are the results not what you expect (why)?

Comment: `data.textContent.indexOf(search)` - `search` is not a string value here, it is the reference to the input field itself. You need to read the `value` of the input field.

Comment: Jamiec：Sorry for that I did't descript my question clearly I've been edit it

Comment: CBroe：Oh!Thank you very much. I lose the 'value' in my code!!

Comment: You just need `if (data.textContent.indexOf(search.value) > -1) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the .value

Here is a shorter and improved script:

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('#phone li');
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('input', function() {
  const val = this.value.trim().toLowerCase(); // remove the two .toLowerCase() if you want to be case sensitive
  lis.forEach(li => li.hidden = search != "" && !li.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(val));
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">
<ul id="phone">
  <li>iPhone 12</li>
  <li>iPhone 12 Pro</li>
  <li>iPhone 12 Pro Max</li>
  <li>iPhone 12 Mini</li>
  <li>iPad Air</li>
  <li>iPad Pro</li>
  <li>iMac</li>
  <li>Mac book Air</li>
  <li>Mac book Pro</li>
  <li>Mac Pro</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the value of your input

```
function search() {
  let search = document.querySelector('#search');
  let li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  for (let data of li) {
    console.log(data.textContent.indexOf(search.value))
    if (data.textContent.indexOf(search.value) > -1) {
      data.style.display = '';
    } else {
      data.style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This issue was already handled in comments. There is [much more to improve here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72882653/295783) - also you should cache the value

Answer (score 0):

You should've to used `.value` to get the value of the text input.
In snippet below `.toLowerCase()` is used. It will display the elements (`li`) regardless of it's case.

```js
function search() {
  let search = document.querySelector('#search').value.toLowerCase();
  let lists = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  const listsLen = lists.length;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < listsLen; ++i) {
    const listContent = lists[i].textContent.toLowerCase();
    if (listContent.indexOf(search) > -1) {
      lists[i].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      lists[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="search()">
<ul id="phone">
  <li>iPhone 12</li>
  <li>iPhone 12 Pro</li>
  <li>iPhone 12 Pro Max</li>
  <li>iPhone 12 Mini</li>
  <li>iPad Air</li>
  <li>iPad Pro</li>
  <li>iMac</li>
  <li>Mac book Air</li>
  <li>Mac book Pro</li>
  <li>Mac Pro</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```